# 2D LiDAR clusters correction

Tags: python-3.x, point-clouds, calibration, lidar

I am trying to do camera-lidar calibration. For that i took some lidar data of a checkerboard. For the extrinsic calibration I selected the corner points of checkerboard in image and in pcd. While selecting the pcd points i noticed that the points for ckecker board is not on the same depth. (I have attached the top view and front view of checkerboard below). Since the points are in different depths, the ectrinsic calibration values I am getting are wrong.

[This is the top view..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NPgm.png)
[This is the front view..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cns83.png)

Is there any preprocessing step that can be done for reducing this kind of spreading in clusters?

Lidar used here : Benewake CE30D